# Can Palisade Cells Survive Independently?

Tags: botany

I have been intrigued by this question. Can palisade cells survive independently from its parent plant in a chemical environment? For example, if we were to separate a palisade cell from a plant and place it in sucrose solution, how long would it survive?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can. In 1902 Haberlandt reported single palisade cell culture from leaves in knop’s salt solution. Now there are many different methods of plant tissue culture

for PLANT TISSUE CULTURE [see](http://www.liv.ac.uk/~sd21/tisscult/what.htm)